# How can I empty the recycle bin on the azure disk space?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I used the url https://MyService.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

to administrate the content of my disk space.

I deleted some very big .log files.

When I look in my azure portal even hours later it still says that 98% of all space is reserved. But I deleted those huge log files.

It seems to me those files are still in the bin trash.

[image]

and there is a $Recycle bin on the system drive but I can not access it => "Access is denied".

How can I wipe the whole trash bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer your primary question, this `$Recycle` folder is part of the base VM, and what's in there is not included in your quota. So you can safely ignore it. See [this article](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#file-system) for more detail on the various types of files. `$Recycle` falls under the "Machine level read-only files" category.

As for your deleted files, sometimes, it can take a while for the change to propagate back to the quota API. And do note that if you have a Free site, your quota is shared between all the Free sites in that resource group.

If you feel the issue is not going away, please share your site name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly), and we'll investigate.

Comment: I run standard not free. I expected from a high scalable service that the quota changes in a 10 second interval at least not 2 hours. If the issue persists until monday I call you ;-)

Comment: Yes, definitely, if it does not update on its own, we want to investigate further, and will need your site name per my answer.

Comment: Now the azure UI diskspace refreshed after the weekend ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply stopping and starting the site? Or using the restart function in the Portal to see if this clears everything for you?

You can also try scaling the web app up and then back down.